# Eclipse gives storing device error

Tags: eclipse, java-me

I'm trying to use Eclipse for J2ME development. I need to import a device from the "Device Management" menu. Whenever i try to import a device it gives me error. The error is: Error storing devices-Could not compile stylesheet.  I'm using Eclipse 3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because I use Windows in Turkish. It is something to do with language packages, i think. I changed my default language in Windows to English and the problem solved.